# System.Diagnostics.EventLog Cannot be Accessed with an Instance Reference

Tags: c#, windows, service, event-log

I'm creating a Windows Service and have a slight issue when trying to write to the EventLog. I have the following code;

```
class WindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    public WindowsService()
    {
        ((ISupportInitialize)this.EventLog).BeginInit();

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(this.ServiceName))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(this.ServiceName, "Application");
        }
        ((ISupportInitialize)this.EventLog).EndInit();
    }
}
```

This is based on the MSDN article and another SO question on here, and it worked up until last night however this morning it doesn't work with the error

*Member 'EventLog.SourceExists(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead*

*Member 'EventLog.CreateEventSource(string, string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead*

I'm not sure why, I've checked against a backup and that too is throwing an error.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: what type is this.ServiceName ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SourceExists` and `CreateEventSource` are static methods, you need to qualify them with the type name rather than an instance variable.  Based on the error and on this:

```
this.EventLog
```

presumably you have an instance variable called `EventLog`.  Rename it to something less confusing, such as `CurrentEventLog`.  Any meaningful name that doesn't conflict with an *existing* name.

Basically, don't name your variables the same as their types.  That's just inviting confusion not only from the compiler but also from anybody who has to maintain that code.

Comment: You're right, I forgot I had merged a table in the database which was already named EventLog, this has been renamed and it is of course working as expected.